# Is there a way to ease in and out an animated div without using negative pixel values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-easing

I am wanting the navigation bar to ease in and out at a certain anchor point. I have accomplished the task, however I am finding that scrolling while the animation is occurring will interrupt the animation due to the negative pixel values and the top of the document. Is there a way to have the navigation use the animation I have setup without using the negative pixel values to hide and show it?

I have tried the .show()/.hide() options with visibility: hidden;, but I cant seem to figure out how to incorporate them with .animate().

```js
var t = $("#about").offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(document).scrollTop() >= t ) {
        $('#global-nav').stop().animate({top: '0px'}, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
    } else {
        $('#global-nav').stop().animate({top: '-50px'}, 500, 'easeInExpo');
    }  
});
```

```css
html { height: 2000px; } 

#global-nav {
    height:50px;
    background:#000;
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: -50px; 
    width: 100%;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    
}
#global-nav p {
    margin-top:15px;
}
#about{
   margin-top:600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="global-nav"><p>Navigation</p>.</div>

<div id="about"></div>
```

This is what I have accomplished so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Hysteresis/0oazqj4y/43/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you rephrase this "I am finding that scrolling while the animation is occurring will interrupt the animation due to the negative pixel values"? Not clear tho. [This looks fine](http://jsfiddle.net/0oazqj4y/50/).

Comment: Sorry about that. I guess the problem lies mostly with the animation when scrolling back up. The animation hesitates/stutters if the user keeps scrolling up since it is trying to find the top of the document to animate back up too. I added a larger margin so you can hopefully see what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/Hysteresis/0oazqj4y/51/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your animation uses `easing` effect and for that it looks like that it's hesitating but if you remove the `easing` effect from when hiding the item then it'll look smother; for example:

```
// Without "easeInExpo" easing effect
else {
    $('#global-nav').stop()
    .animate({top: '-50px'}, 500);
}
```

[This looks smooth.](http://jsfiddle.net/0oazqj4y/52/)

Comment: I would have to agree. Thank you! I liked the ease in effect, but it was causing the problem. That's why I was curious if there was another way to hide the navigation besides using negative pixel values, but this is a good fix for now. I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome and I already provided an updated example in the comment, probably you didn't notice it :-)

Comment: Ah yes, I see that now. Thanks again!